# Error null reference in left join

Tags: c#, linq

When i comment `dishes.Add(new Dishes { DishID = 8, DishName = "Name", DishTypeID = 2, IngredientID = 2 });` i get in `ll` one item `Amount="1 cup" DishID=1 Ingridient="egg" Name ="Soup"`. When uncomment that line raising error, null reference exception in `b.IngredientTypeID`. The main question how to get in `ll` two item's:

1) `Amount="1 cup" DishID=1 Ingridient="egg" Name ="Soup"`

2) `Amount=null DishID=2 Ingridient=null Name =null`

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Dishes> dishes = new List<Dishes>();
        List<Ingredients> ingredients = new List<Ingredients>();
        List<Amount> amount = new List<Amount>();
        List<Ingredient> ingredient = new List<Ingredient>();

        dishes.Add(new Dishes { DishID = 1, DishName = "Soup", DishTypeID = 1, IngredientID = 1 });
        //dishes.Add(new Dishes { DishID = 8, DishName = "Name", DishTypeID = 2, IngredientID = 2 }); 
        ingredients.Add(new Ingredients { AmountID = 2, IngredientID = 1, IngredientTypeID = 1, IngredientUniqID = 1 });
        amount.Add(new Amount { AmountID = 2, AmountName = "1 cup" });
        ingredient.Add(new Ingredient { IngredientID = 1, IngredientName = "egg" });

        var test = from dish in dishes
                   join ing in ingredients on dish.IngredientID equals ing.IngredientID into result
                   from b in result.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   join i in ingredient on b.IngredientTypeID equals i.IngredientID into r
                   from c in r.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   join am in amount on b.AmountID equals am.AmountID into s
                   from t in s.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new DisplayRecipe { Name = dish.DishName, Amount = t.AmountName, Ingredient = c.IngredientName, DishID = dish.DishID };

        List<DisplayRecipe> ll = test.ToList();
    }
}
public partial class Dishes
{
    public int DishID { get; set; }
    public string DishName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DishTypeID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IngredientID { get; set; }
}

public partial class Ingredients
{
    public int IngredientID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AmountID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IngredientTypeID { get; set; }
    public int IngredientUniqID { get; set; }
}

public partial class Amount
{
    public int AmountID { get; set; }
    public string AmountName { get; set; }
}
public partial class Ingredient
{
    public int IngredientID { get; set; }
    public string IngredientName { get; set; }
}
public class DisplayRecipe
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ingredient { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public int DishID { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: ingridients and ingridient two different lists. It's problem with bad naming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that any of the `b`, `c`, `t` variables can be `null` due to `DefaultIfEmpty` and you need to account for that in any member access, including join conditions.

If you are using C#6 (VS2015), you can use `?.` operator like this

```
var test = from dish in dishes
           join ing in ingredients on dish.IngredientID equals ing.IngredientID into result
           from b in result.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join i in ingredient on b?.IngredientTypeID equals i.IngredientID into r
           from c in r.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join am in amount on b?.AmountID equals am.AmountID into s
           from t in s.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new DisplayRecipe { Name = dish.DishName, Amount = t?.AmountName, Ingredient = c?.IngredientName, DishID = dish.DishID };
```

while in pre C#6:

```
var test = from dish in dishes
           join ing in ingredients on dish.IngredientID equals ing.IngredientID into result
           from b in result.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join i in ingredient on b != null ? b.IngredientTypeID : null equals i.IngredientID into r
           from c in r.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join am in amount on b != null ? b.AmountID : null equals am.AmountID into s
           from t in s.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new DisplayRecipe { Name = dish.DishName, Amount = t != null ? t.AmountName : null, Ingredient = c != null ? c.IngredientName : null, DishID = dish.DishID };
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you added this line:

```
dishes.Add(new Dishes { DishID = 8, DishName = "Name", DishTypeID = 2, IngredientID = 2 });
```

But did not also add the other lines that are dependent on your join (example):

```
ingredients.Add(new Ingredients { AmountID = 2, IngredientID = 2, IngredientTypeID = 1, IngredientUniqID = 1 });
ingredient.Add(new Ingredient { IngredientID = 2, IngredientName = "ham" });
```

So when your program tries to find an ingredientID of 2 because that has been added to dishes it does not find one and produces an error.

Sample of code that works:

```
        dishes.Add(new Dishes { DishID = 1, DishName = "Soup", DishTypeID = 1, IngredientID = 1 });
    dishes.Add(new Dishes { DishID = 8, DishName = "Name", DishTypeID = 2, IngredientID = 2 }); 
    ingredients.Add(new Ingredients { AmountID = 2, IngredientID = 1, IngredientTypeID = 1, IngredientUniqID = 1 });
    ingredients.Add(new Ingredients { AmountID = 2, IngredientID = 2, IngredientTypeID = 1, IngredientUniqID = 1 });
    amount.Add(new Amount { AmountID = 2, AmountName = "1 cup" });
    ingredient.Add(new Ingredient { IngredientID = 1, IngredientName = "egg" });
    ingredient.Add(new Ingredient { IngredientID = 2, IngredientName = "ham" });
```